# Multi-Cluster Kubernetes Service Discovery using Consul and Spring Cloud Consul

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, microservices, consul, spring-cloud-consul

Alright, so I have two **bare metal** Kubernetes clusters, with no cloud providers. I have microservices written in **spring boot**. Now I want to build a production grade service discovery mechanism for inter-service communication.

> My basic intention is to support **multi-cluster service to service
>   communication**. So a microservice-1 on cluster-1 should be able to call
>   microservice-2 on cluster-2. Fair enough ?

In pursuit of this, I spent countless hours in researching. I explored Native Kubernetes Service Discovery, Istio, Eureka etc but none of these could really serve my purpose.

I am finally thinking to settle down on **Hashicorp’s Consul** and **Spring Cloud Consul** project.

With the help of Consul’s **Service Syncing**, I was able to register the Kubernetes services (of type NodePort) to Consul on one cluster. So for now my Kubernetes cluster-1 and consul server are on the same Linux machine.

> *I have enabled **spring cloud consul** in my spring boot services but
>   disabled their registration to Consul because if I enable the
>   registration, Kubernetes pods will get registered in Consul. I want
>   the Kubernetes Services to get registered so that when a client asks
>   Consul about a target service, Consul can return the host and nodePort
>   of the target service. Host and nodePort will enable me to call
>   services across the clusters.*

I have two questions for the community :

1. I want to deploy microservices on the second Kubernetes cluster and register them to the consul server of the first machine basically to keep all the service registry at one place. I don’t want to install another Consul server on the second cluster and moreover Consul-1 and Consul-2 will be mutually out of sync. So second installation is a no go. How can I solve this ?
2. I want to load balance on the client side using **Ribbon**. I want to load balance between two Kubernetes services returned by Consul. How can I do that ?

Also, if you guys have any better suggestions for achieving what I want then please let me know.

Apologies for a long textual question.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? I am also looking for similar one

Comment: No. Our project was moved to cloud so we escaped the pain of setting up service discovery on bare metal servers.